# Parallax Split screen with alternating scroll sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am looking to create a simple parallax split screen site that allows me to once a new screen is loaded alternate the scrolling. For example, If I scroll down and the content on the left and right appear I want to then lock the right side and have scrolling only happen on the left until that content is finished.

So it should start like this:

http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/multiscroll-js-jquery-plugin-to-create-multi-scrolling-sites-with-two-vertical-layouts/

but once the section loads in I need just the left scrollable like this:

http://www.themealings.com.au/leesa/portfolio/nick-jr-parents-blog/

Once the left side content is complete I want to present a new section.  Any ideas on how this can happen? What is the best JS library to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plug-ins that can accomplish this quite easily.

Give this a shot -----> http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em

Demo here: -----> http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-Stickem/

I am currently using this hard code to accomplish something similar, so this might be of use as well:

```
    var $window = $(window),
    $mainMenuBar = $('#fixed-div'), //This div will scroll until top
    $menuBarOffset = $mainMenuBar.offset().top,
    window_top = 0,
    footer_offset = $("#end-div").offset().top, //this div tells #fixed-div when to start scrolling
    content = $("#unaffected-div"), //This div scrolls like normal
    panel_height = $mainMenuBar.outerHeight()+'px';


$window.scroll(function() {
    window_top = $window.scrollTop();

    if (window_top >= $menuBarOffset) {
        if (window_top >= footer_offset) {
            $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
            content.css('margin-top', 0);
        } else {
            $mainMenuBar.addClass('stick');
            content.css('margin-top', panel_height);
        }
    }
    else {
        $mainMenuBar.removeClass('stick');
        content.css('margin-top', 0);
    }
});
```

You will also need to add this element to your .css file

```
.stick {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried using stick-em but with no luck. I am using Foundation as the frame work and it disables the positioning on the container. The script is loaded but it is not but it not activating the class change. I am going to monkey with it some more. If I can't figure it out I will an example page. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Here is an example - so simple yet not sure what the problem can be http://cpawl.com/test/scroll/

Comment: The reason stickem is not working, is because it is not loading the plugin script properly. It looks like you have not yet loaded any jQuery library

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

include this as the first script link in your document, and see if you have any better results

Comment: Yes that what it was - had jquery loading in the footer. Thanks. Got it working but probably going to scrap it anyway. Now the issue is if the window is re-sized it stops working.